# How do I change the default permissions of home directories created with adduser?

Tags: permissions, home-directory, chmod

How can I change the default chmod of new home directories (created with adduser)?

Comment: @Rinzwind There are many good reasons someone might want to do this. They might want to grant group write permission, to share files with another trusted user added to the owner's primary group. Or they might want to lock down permissions, so by default users cannot read each other's files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change this permanently for all new users you need to alter

```
/etc/adduser.conf
```

Find the option `DIR_MODE` and set it to the permissions you want it to be.

In general you do not need write permissions for others (if you do set it to write access anyone from "outside" is able to **delete** that dir. That is if they can access your machine of course).

Comment: A `6` or a `2` would be just about as bad (both give all users write permission). Also, this answer says how to *change the permission* of the directory once created, but the question is asking *how to change the defaults, so the directory will be created initially with different permissions*.

Comment: ah missed that :) edited it in :+ @EliahKagan