# DIR_MODE=0755 to DIR_MODE=0750 does not work for newly added users

Tags: permissions, users

I have been following [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/615990/1695376), [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1487695/1695376), and [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/163243/1089494). All of these solutions suggest to change `DIR_MODE=0755` to `DIR_MODE=0750` to prevent newly added users to be accessed by other users. I went ahead and changed `DIR_MODE=0750` using `sudo vim /etc/adduser.conf` and save the file. Now, I expect new users have only permission set to `750`. When I created `user1` using `sudo useradd -m user1`, the home directory of the `user1` still has `755 or drwxr-xr-x` permission. I check using `ls -ld /home/user1` and get `drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Jun  2 04:38 user1`.
I can do `chmod` for this user but I want this to be done automatically.
I do not want to use `umask` because it sets the permission globally on the file system and not only for the user home directory. Also, this [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1487695/1695376) does not support it.

**What am I mission and what is wrong with my solution?**

**Note1:**

I am doing all the above in VM on GCP and use `ubuntu 18`.

**Note2:**

I am adding a user using `useradd` command and adding user using `adduser` works fine. I want to do it using `useradd` not `adduser`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same results on 20.04 under Azure.  I have DIR_MODE=0750, rebooted, created a new user, and I still see 755 as the created permissions.

This worked for me https://superuser.com/a/304000/630695

> *"The home directory (`/home/username`) is subject to the `UMASK` setting in `/etc/login.defs`. This is set to `022` by default, so the permissions for `/home/username` becomes `755`."*

Comment: Here is how you would do it:
Open `sudo vim /etc/adduser.conf`
Change `DIR_MODE=0755 to DIR_MODE=0750`. This will change the mode for newly added users NOT the previous ones. Also, it works when you would add users with `adduser` not `useradd` command.

Comment: the above solution need not using `UMASK`.

Comment: @Sepide the adduser.conf is the first thing I tried, but it sadly did not work (even rebooted to make sure).  The UMASK seemed to be the only reliable way in my case.  I think there is a bug somewhere in the processes that checks adduser.conf.